# Sum up non-unique rows in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id = [1,1,2,3]
x1 = [0,1,1,2]
x2 = [2,3,1,1]

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':id, 'x1':x1, 'x2':x2})

df
id  x1  x2
1   0   2
1   1   3
2   1   1
3   2   1
```

Some rows have the same `id`. I want to sum up such rows (over `x1` and `x2`) to obtain a new dataframe with unique `ids`:

```
df_new
id  x1  x2
1   1   5
2   1   1
3   2   1
```

An important detail is that the real number of columns `x1`, `x2`,... is large, so I cannot apply a function that requires manual input of column names.

Comment: `df.groupby(df.id).sum()` you may want to `reset_index()` afterwards if you want to keep everything as columns.

Comment: `df.groupby('id', as_index=False).sum()` instead of `df.groupby('id').sum().reset_index()` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed you can use pandas `groupby` function to sum based on the `id` value:

```
df.groupby(df.id).sum()
# or
df.groupby('id').sum()
```

If you need don't want `id` to become the index then you can:

```
df.groupby('id').sum().reset_index()
# or
df.groupby('id', as_index=False).sum()   # @John_Gait
```

Answer (score 0):

With `pivot_table`:

```
In [31]: df.pivot_table(index='id', aggfunc=sum)
Out[31]:
    x1  x2
id
1    1   5
2    1   1
3    2   1
```